# Regular expression to find and remove a sub-string or its variants from a string

Tags: python, regex

I have text of the type:

- "Choice values selected: Option 1, or Option 2, or Option 3"
- "Choice value selected: Option 1, or Option 2, or Option 3"
- "Choice value selected = Option 1 , or Option 2, or Option 3"

I need to extract everything that is after the `:` or `=`

I have tried to go about it this way:

```
import regex as re
r = re.compile(r'Choice(.+?)selected')
r.split(str)
```

I don't know how to capture the `:` or `=`

Comment: Just `re.split` should be enough @alannaC

Comment: ok darn yes that didn't occur to me. :facepalm:

Comment: No issues, I have done the same in my answer below! Please check it and accept it if it helped you :) @alannaC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use regex, just use `re.split` to split both on `:` and `=`

```
li = ["Choice values selected: Option 1, or Option 2, or Option 3", "Choice value selected: Option 1, or Option 2, or Option 3",
      "Choice value selected = Option 1 , or Option 2, or Option 3"]

import re
for item in li:
    #Split on : and =, get the last element from list and strip it
    print(re.split(':|=',item)[1].strip())
```

The output will be

```
Option 1, or Option 2, or Option 3
Option 1, or Option 2, or Option 3
Option 1 , or Option 2, or Option 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex,

```
[:=]\s*(.*)
```

And get your value from group1

This regex starts by capturing either `:` or `=` and then optionally `\s*` matches optional space and then `(.*)` captures the remaining text in the line and captures in group1

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6bC8qw/1)**

Python code,

```
import regex as re

arr = ['Choice values selected: Option 1, or Option 2, or Option 3','Choice value selected: Option 1, or Option 2, or Option 3','Choice value selected = Option 1 , or Option 2, or Option 3']

for s in arr:
 m = re.search(r'[:=]\s*(.*)', s)
 if m:
  print(s, '-->', m.group(1))
```

Output,

```
Choice values selected: Option 1, or Option 2, or Option 3 --> Option 1, or Option 2, or Option 3
Choice value selected: Option 1, or Option 2, or Option 3 --> Option 1, or Option 2, or Option 3
Choice value selected = Option 1 , or Option 2, or Option 3 --> Option 1 , or Option 2, or Option 3
```

Also, in case you want to use `re.split` then you can split it using `[=:]` regex which represents either `=` or `:`

```
import regex as re
arr = ['Choice values selected: Option 1, or Option 2, or Option 3','Choice value selected: Option 1, or Option 2, or Option 3','Choice value selected = Option 1 , or Option 2, or Option 3']

for s in arr:
 r = re.compile(r'[:=]')
 print(r.split(s)[1])
```

Output,

```
 Option 1, or Option 2, or Option 3
 Option 1, or Option 2, or Option 3
 Option 1 , or Option 2, or Option 3
```